# Bash conditional commands

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, sh

I have a string of commands I want to run in succession, if the previous command has been successful. Here is an example:

```
echo "hello" && sleep 5 && cd /tmp && rm -r * && echo "googbye"
```

If any part fails, I need to know which part failed. Also, I am trying to implement a spinner while the commands are running. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of detecting which bit failed, you could use:

```
bad=0
[[ $bad -eq 0 ]] && { echo hello   || bad=1; }
[[ $bad -eq 0 ]] && { sleep 5      || bad=2; }
[[ $bad -eq 0 ]] && { cd /tmp      || bad=3; }
[[ $bad -eq 0 ]] && { rm -r *      || bad=4; }
[[ $bad -eq 0 ]] && { echo goodbye || bad=5; }
```

The variable `bad` would then be set based on which bit failed (if any).

Alternatively, if that's too verbose, you can still *do* it in a single line, albeit a longer one:

```
 bad=1 && echo hello && bad=2 && sleep 5 && bad=3 && cd /tmp && bad=4 && echo goodbye && bad=0
```

---

In terms of a spinner, that may not work so well if you actually have output in the job you're doing but you can do it with a simple background function:

```
spinner() {
    while : ; do
        echo -ne '\b|'  ; sleep 1
        echo -ne '\b/'  ; sleep 1
        echo -ne '\b-'  ; sleep 1
        echo -ne '\b\\' ; sleep 1
    done
}

echo -n 'Starting: .'
spinner & pid=$!
sleep 13 ; kill $pid
echo
echo Done.
```

---

With regard to putting it all together based on your question and comments, I'd probably have *two* functions, the first to run the spinner in the background and the second to do the payload, including capturing its output so it doesn't affect the spinner.

To that end, have a look at the following demo code:

```
spinner() {
    echo -n 'Starting: .'
    chars='\-/|'
    while [[ -f "$1" ]] ; do
        echo -ne "\b${chars:3}" ; sleep 1
        chars="${chars:3}${chars:0:3}"
    done
    echo -e ' .. done.'
}

payload() {
    echo Running task 1
    sleep 3
    true || return 1

    echo Running task 2
    sleep 3
    false || return 2

    echo Running task 3
    sleep 3
    true || return 3

    return 0
}

touch /tmp/sentinel.$$
spinner /tmp/sentinel.$$ & pid=$!

payload >/tmp/out.$$ 2>&1 ; rc=$?

rm /tmp/sentinel.$$ ; wait

echo "Return code was $rc, output was:"
cat /tmp/out.$$
rm /tmp/out.$$
```

In the payload function, simply replace each of the steps with whatever you wish to actually do (such as shut down a `systemd` job or delete some files).

The code as it stands will fail step 2 (`false`) but, for your own code, this would be running *actual* commands and evaluating their return value.

I've also used a sentinel file to terminate the spinner function so that it's not shut down "violently".

Comment: At the end of this, `badbit` will be either 0 or 5, nothing else. If it becomes non-zero, each subsequent line becomes `false && thing || badbit=n`. Because `false && thing` evaluates to false, the shell will evaluate `badbit=n` each time. Try it by replacing each command with `false` and see that badbit does not point to the first failure.

Comment: You can fix it by doing `[[ $badbit -eq 0 ]] && { command || badbit=1; }`

Comment: Thanks, @camh, have put your fix into the answer.

Comment: Can I encapsulate the entire `[[ $badbit -eq 0 ]] && { command }` sequence as one process for the spinner? Edit: So if I use your one-line example, I can just `$(COMMAND) &` for the spinner

Comment: @EricWolf, I'd simply replace the `sleep 13` in my demo code with whatever payload you want to run. I'm not sure whether those are the *actual* commands you're using but, if they are, you can simply use `rm -r /tmp/* >/dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: No, they're not. The commands are more like `systemctl stop PROC && cd /tmp && wget FILE && tar xf FILE && rsync -a FILE FOLDER && rm FILE && systemctl start PROC`

Comment: I've figured `systemctl stop PROC || { echo "FAIL AT STOP"; exit; }`, not sure if this is better or not, it should exit the script at the failure point.